# Installing Epson L380 - problems

Tags: printing

I am unable to install Epson L380 on ubuntu 16.04.
Epson's website does not have the driver for l380.
I tried with driver for l385, but it does not work properly.
Thanks in advance!
Manu

Comment: There is a driver for L380 on the Epson site. http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu, go to Printers > Add Printer. In the printer selection module, select Epson and then select L310. That makes my printer work (It's an Epson L380)

Comment: This tip worked for me. I am using 18.04. I went to "Printer Properties" window and changed the model from Epson L380 to Epson L310.

Answer (score 0):

For greater compatibility WYSIWYG (What You See Is What You Get) it is recommended to install the software original of Epson.

1. sudo apt-get install lsb
2. Download Installers: http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule

a. Here, indicate your printer model and operating system. Example: L380 and Linux.
b. For Ubuntu-based distributions select the packages suitable: .deb (printer) or tar.gz (Scanner).

Example: 
- epson-printer-utility_1.0.2-1lsb3.2_i386.deb (double click)
- imagescan-bundle-ubuntu-18.04-1.3.40.x64.deb.tar.gz (uncompress / sudo ./install.sh)
- epson-printer-utility_1.0.2-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb (optional)