# Ubuntu 14.04.4, Epson L380 driver

Tags: 14.04, printing, epson

I just bought Epson L 380, in Linux 14.04.4 64 bit, want to install Epson L380 printer but I don’t have the drivers. The printer driver is needed, please help me the link or the .deb file.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/q/962996/250300

Answer (score 2):

so one starts here http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX

then enters L380 you end up here http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=EN&CN2=&DSCMI=56239&DSCCHK=dbc1e2f3eac59d452517e4486ca608382b28ef04

so click the ACCEPT button and for64bit Ubuntu you need epson-inkjet-printer-201601w_1.0.0-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb

if you click to download that, browsers such as Firefox should offer OPEN .. which means gdebi installer so that should install the drivers.

to get a printer working you need to do at least two things
1) install the drivers
2) register the printer on lpadmin

if 2) isn't generated when the drivers are installed, go to the PRINTERS folder and click the ADD button to get the L380 registered